# SwitchPreference with Material Design in Android Lollipop?

Tags: android, switchpreference

I've upgraded the code to Android Lollipop but the SwitchPreference still looks the same with the on/off design.

Is it possible to change it to the new Material Design look of a normal Switch ?

Comment: it seems you are out of luck https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/#comment-1645436948

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26724566/create-own-switchcompat-preference